# adding  web reference in dotnetnuke package creation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, dotnetnuke-5

i am trying to create a dotnetnuke module which will be installable .in this module i am using a web service but when i am installing this module on another dnn portal it shows error  which is in following image you can find below

on dnn forum my situation is similar to [this](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/-1/postid/224434/scope/posts.aspx) but i didnt find the soluiton yet.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this problem before with my module not being able to access a web service. Please make sure the portal you are installing the module on, can access the said web service to rule this out.

Comment: i didnt get your point? will u please elaborate it more for me . i am in very urgent need for me.

Comment: e.g. I developed the web service and the module on Portal A which was on machine A. Then I installed the module on Portal B, which was on machine B. My web service was internal and whenever machine B was not connected to my network, I used to see this error. Once my web service went live and was on the internet, I haven't seen this error. Hope that helps!

Comment: oh thats what i am missing thanks dear , really very much thanks

Comment: how can i add the reference in the module which i am created.so on any pc this service can be used

Comment: Nothing different about how you add references. The web service needs to be configured so that it can be accessed from all machines the module is installed on. If you plan to use the module within your organization, then the web service needs to be available on the office n/w. If you plan to distribute/sell the module, then the web service needs to be public, accessible by everyone on the internet. Ask your n/w admin for instructions on how to achieve that. 
edit: The machine on which the module is installed on, should also be able to access the web service (check for n/w or firewall problems)